# Is a function $f$:$\mathbb R^n$->$\mathbb R$ continuous with a finite limit bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to know if a function $f$:$\mathbb R^n$->$\mathbb R$ continuous with a finite limit when $||x||$ tends to infinity is bounded ? if yes why ?

I already proved that it is true for $f$:$\mathbb R$->$\mathbb R$  continuous with a finite limit is bounded ?

Also is there some kind of correlation between de the two cases ?

Comment: MathJax tip: "\to" generates $\to$, "\colon" generates $\colon$, e.g. $f \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ .

Comment: Both of the statement could be proved by using the property of continuous functions that defined on compact sets.